# How can an empty directory be in use and how do I do it on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, io, directory

On Windows I have an empty directory which I cannot delete because it is "in use". After restarting, I can delete this directory. This happens occasionally, and it confuses me.

I am quite familiar with the Win32 API, but I have no idea what it means for an empty directory to be "in use". (And yes, I have hidden files and folders set to visible.)

How do I make this happen myself? What Win32 API calls should I make to make an empty directory of my choice "in use"?

Comment: in use - mean open handles to file exist. empty this file or not - not play any role

Comment: The Windows API abstracts how it accesses paths that are relative to the current directory, and also how it protects the current directory from being deleted. The currently supported versions of Windows are implemented over NT. In this case, Windows keeps a handle open for the working directory, which doesn't share delete access. It uses this handle as the `RootDirectory` in the NT `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` when accessing a relative path if the target is at or below the current directory, but not above it since path parsing in NT doesn't implement ".." parent access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody has a open handle to the directory. Usually by `SetCurrentDirectory`, or the current directory in cmd.exe or sometimes by `CreateFile`.

Use the handle search in [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find open handles to a specific directory.